# Pants: Generate Python from Protocol Buffers

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, pants

Is it possible to generate Python code from Protocol Buffers message definitions using Pants?

Looking through [the documentation](https://pantsbuild.github.io) and [the examples](https://github.com/pantsbuild/pants/tree/master/examples) of Pants I was unable to find any instructions how to generate Python code from Protocol Buffers message definitions. Only Java seems to be supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently (as of 0.0.63) there are no targets or rules defined to generate python in OSS pants.